# How to create a compressed archive of entire storage unit in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a compressed backup of my eMMC (which has multiple primary partitions) using a Python3 script. I want to mimic the behaviour of piping the output of `dd` to `bzip2` or `xz`. I have tried the two following approaches:

### Incremental Compressor

```
import bz2
import time
import binascii

compressor = bz2.BZ2Compressor()

with open('/dev/mmcblk0', 'rb') as src_handle:
    with open('/media/usb0/backup_emmc.bz2', 'wb') as dest_handle:
        last_check = time.time()
        read = 0
        written = 0
        chunksize_bytes = 10485760  # 10 MB
        while True:
            input = src_handle.read(chunksize_bytes)
            if not input:
                print("Flushing remaining data")
                remaining_data = compressor.flush()
                dest_handle.write(binascii.hexlify(remaining_data))
                print("Copying complete")
                break
            else:
                written += dest_handle.write(binascii.hexlify(compressor.compress(input)))
                if time.time() - last_check >= 1:
                    last_check = time.time()
                    print("Read {:.2f} MB".format(read / (1024.0**2)))
                    print("Written {:.2f} MB".format(written / (1024.0**2)))
                read += chunksize_bytes
```

### Writing to Compressed File

```
import bz2
import shutil
with open('/dev/mmcblk0', 'rb') as src_handle:
    with bz2.BZ2File('/media/usb0/backup_emmc.bz2', 'wb', compresslevel=9) as dest_handle:
        shutil.copyfileobj(src_handle, dest_handle)
```

Both of these methods produce a tiny file, which cannot possibly be a compressed archive made of my entire eMMC. When I copy back using `bzip2` and `dd`, the content of the storage is no longer readable. Other than using bash utilities through subprocess, what would be the correct pythonic way of doing it?